# Instruments shows memory leak - Xcode 9.4 and Simulator iPhoneX 11.4

Tags: ios, xcode, instruments

While profiling my app for memory leaks, instruments shows leaks in the following piece of code -

```
let viewController = (UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HistoryView") as! HistoryViewController
```

This is the method where i am using this code -

```
@objc func historyButtonAction(sender : UIButton)
    {
        let viewController = (UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HistoryView") as! HistoryViewController
        viewController.account = self.account;
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true);
    }
```

Could not resolve this leak. Would appreciate any help to understand this.

Comment: Code looks fine, don't worry Instruments may not give the exact leak sometimes, it gives  an idea where it might leak so that you can investigate more on that.

Comment: Are you doing something in `account` property setter? Does, for instance, `account` object keep reference to view controller?

Comment: account is a custom object, i am passing from current viewcontroller to HistoryViewController.